# Type is missing the following properties from type

Tags: angular, typescript

I have the following interface in a typescript file.

```
export interface TempContext {
  FriendlyName?: boolean;
  hList: SelectFilterListItem[];
}
```

SelectFilterListItem is an interface in another file

```
export interface SelectFilterListItem {
  name: string;
  value: any;
}
```

I then want to use this in a function in the same file

```
filterDef: new SelectFilterDef({
        filterList: (context: TempContext) => context.hList,
      }),
```

I get the following error

> Type '(context: TempContext) => SelectFilterListItem[]' is missing the
>   following properties from type 'SelectFilterListItem[]': pop, push,
>   concat, join, and 25 more.

Comment: How does the last snippet relate to the first two? What is SelectFilterDef? What is filterList? The error is linked to something you didn't post: you're supposed to pass an array of SelectFilterListItem, and you pass a function instead.

Comment: It is a custom built (not by me) control that contains far too much code to post here (it also contains sensitive info that I can not post). However "filterList" can take a function although there are no examples of that happening in any of the code. But I have been assured that it can take a function despite my thoughts that it can not. I will pursue this again with the other developer.

Answer (score 0):

According to me as your `hList` is not optional, you have to provide value of type `SelectFilterListItem` to `context.hList` as `hList` is of type `SelectFilterListItem[]` i.e. array of objects

hence your `filterDef` will get changed to

```
    filterDef: new SelectFilterDef({
               filterList: (context: TempContext) => {
               context.hList = [{name: 'Test1',value: 'val1'},{name: 'Test2',value: 'val2'}]
               }
            })
```

Comment: hList is populated in the angular Controller so at this point it should be an array of objects. However it will not even compile so it can't be that can it?

Comment: here you need to set or have value of hList always of type SelectFilterListItem[] else angular compiler will throw type error

Comment: Also I have just tried your suggestion but I still get the compiler error.

Comment: ok, that means you have to set value of hList strictly of type  SelectFilterListItem before you pass context parameter inside filterList function, OR there might be different keys you have mentioned in SelectFilterListItem interface  which are not name and value , so in this case also compiler will throw error

Comment: can you console.log(context) inside filterList function ??and  change type of context to any like this - (context: any) then share  that console output  here

Answer (score 0):

import file of `SelectFilterListItem` in `TempContext` file like this.

import {SelectFilterListItem} from "some path";

then it will work.

Comment: also replace like this 
`export interface TempContext {
  FriendlyName?: boolean;
  hList: Array<SelectFilterListItem>;
}`